# How do I get the absolute URL when using l()?

Tags: navigation

I want to get `<a href="http://site.ru/node/123">New product</a>` from `l()`, and I
call it as `l('New product', 'node/123')`, but this function generates a URL that is not absolute.

How can I generate an absolute URL with `l()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can make a link absolute with:

```
l(t('New product'), 'node/123', array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

See [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7) and [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/7) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7) and the options in [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/7) for how to construct a link with or without http: but basically you need to set the absolute option to TRUE.