# How to create absolute url for a page/node?

Tags: theming, navigation

I think that I need to use the l() function as seen here: [How do I get the absolute URL when using l()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18124/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-url-when-using-l)

I just need a bit more clarification. What's the best way to create links on pages? I would like to link them correctly so that if my domain changes then the link will be updated (for example going from a local host to an online host). Let me also know if this is not the best way to do it.

I guess I need to know what would go into HTML tag  and then also do I need to place any code anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `l()` and `url()` functions as specified in the answer to the question you link to. Those are core Drupal functions so nothing else is needed.

Comment: I put the link in my page.tpl.php file and it worked perfectly, but when I tried putting that same link in a block it wouldn't. Any ideas why? My Link:

   <?php l(t('About'), 'node/123', array('absolute' => TRUE));?>

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. In the block prefs I need to list it as having "PHP code" not HTML. Thanks!

Comment: That is correct. Although you should try to avoid using the PHP input filter if possible.

Comment: how would you recommend that I add links in blocks then? Is there a better way?

Comment: It really depends on the situation. You can make a custom module which provide the block, or you can override the block with a template file. You can use input filter such as [Path Filter](http://drupal.org/project/pathfilter) (D6) or [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) (D7). On the other hand, if it's just one link in a block perhaps it's not a big deal to make a static link to `/mypage`.